# Two different ways of constructing the convex combination of two sets

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, convex-analysis

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are both subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and convex.
Let
\begin{equation*}
C=\left\{z\in \mathbb{R}^n \vert z=\alpha x+\left(1-\alpha\right)y, x \in A, y\in B, \alpha \in \left[0,1\right]\right\}, 
\end{equation*} that is just the convex hull of $A \cup B$.

Suppose there is a one-to-one mapping between $A$ and $B$, denoted by $f$. Consider the following set where the convex combination is more restrictive:
\begin{equation*}
D=\left\{z\in \mathbb{R}^n \vert z=\alpha x+\left(1-\alpha\right)y, x \in A, y\in B, y=f\left(x\right), \alpha \in \left[0,1\right]\right\}.
\end{equation*}

Apparently $D\subseteq C$. I was wondering whether $D=C$. I tried to construct a counterexample by drawing graphs but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample in two dimensions: Two parallel segments
$$
 A = \{ (x, 0) \mid 0 \le x \le 1 \} \\
 B = \{ (x, 1) \mid 0 \le x \le 1 \}
$$
and the function $f:A \to B$, $f(x, y) = (1-x, 1)$.

The set $D$ consists of all segments from points $(x, 0) \in A$ to $(1-x, 1) \in B$, and does not contain the point $(0, 1/2)$, which  is in the convex hull of $A \cup B$.

Comment: So $D$ is like an hourglass while $C$ is a rectangle, right?

Comment: @Ypbor: Yes, exactly.